# Are there any countries that exempt people who recovered from COVID-19 infection from quarantine or testing?

Tags: international-travel, covid-19, quarantine

Are there any countries that consider people who survived a COVID-19 infection as immune people and let them in without quarantine or testing?

I am currently recovering and should be considered fully recovered in 5 days (according to the local protocol), so I thought I would take a few days off and go somewhere since I haven't hit the road in almost 6 months now.

Comment: If I understand you right, you are looking for destinations where you can show proof of prior infection and recovery on entry and be granted exemption from the "standard" testing or quarantine requirements. Is that correct?

Comment: @RobertColumbia yes, exactly

Comment: Glad to hear you're in the mend, get well soon!

Comment: *"The possibility of reinfection is certainly real,"* https://eu.usatoday.com/story/news/health/2020/07/16/covid-19-can-you-get-infected-twice-herd-immunity/5429012002/ - why not go somewhere in you country of residence?

Comment: To be fair there are many countries that let selected nationalities in without quarantine or testing regardless of immunity status.

Comment: @Anders I was looking for countries that have a specific exemption for those who were previously infected.

Comment: @NeanDerThal but it still fulfills your goal of going somewhere

Comment: @Anders but it does not fill the question which was asked. plus, my nationality is not listed in any exemption.

Comment: The situation regarding immunity after recovery is still very much unknown. Unfortunately, the first signs are actually might not be much in the way of such immunity.

Comment: Creio que seja um pouco precipitado qualquer autoridade afirmar ou não sobre o fato dos pacientes recém recuperados estarem imunes ao vírus. ----------
via Google Translate: I believe that it is a little hasty for any authority to say or not about the fact that newly recovered patients are immune to the virus.

Comment: @Jasper in addition, there seems to be several distinct strains of COVID-19 going around depending on where in the world you are, and interactions between those strains are definitely an unknown at the moment.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What you describe is called an **immunity passport**, but while there's been lots of discussion about them, to date **there are no countries that issue or accept them**.  See the Wikipedia article for details:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immunity_passport

Comment: Because they’re a rather complex idea with some serious dangers.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I totally agree. In fact, there is no proven test up to now that can detect if one had developed antibodies against coronavirus

Comment: Yet we can't leave our houses until we've got "herd immunity". >:( `</rant>`

Comment: @FreeMan more likely when a vaccine or an effective treatment is found.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Antibody tests exist. Are you suggesting they're unreliable, or do you mean that we don't know whether, or to what level, having the antibodies actually confers immunity?

Comment: @NeanDerThal i doubt that this will be a thing because there is evidence that reinfection within weeks or months is a possibility with this virus, so countries are going to test and isolate you regardless.

Comment: @Wossname to start with, yes.  What Does your comment mean? Are you challenging my claim that they're a rather complex idea with some serious dangers, or do you actually want be redpilled on why that's so?   If the latter, I can recommend an *almost excellent*  Q&A site... lol

Comment: @Wossname The Wikipedia article goes into this in some detail, but there's a long list of conditions that need to be true before immunity passports make sense.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  Sorry, my comment should have been directed at Nean Der Thal who seemed to be suggesting there were no antibody tests. I was just seeking clarification.

Comment: @lambshaanxy mainly that human nature needs to stop being what it is lol.

Answer (score 3):

I know that Slovenia at least allows this.
https://www.slovenia.info/en/plan-your-trip/all-you-need-to-know-for-a-healthy-and-safe-vacation-in-slovenia

Answer (score -1):

[Timatic](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php) offers a map where you can tap on a country and see details.  For most countries, you can see just what the restrictions are.

Don't know how accurate Timatic is—they say only Mexico and Afghanistan have no restrictions, while [Kayak](https://www.kayak.com/travel-restrictions) has very different data, which they claim is updated daily.

Comment: The question asked about places where you can be exempted from restrictions by showing prior infection, not about places where there are no restrictions for anyone.

Comment: Edited to more clearly show intent.

Comment: I still don't think it addresses the question asked. The question is asking about scenarios like "By default everyone entering must quarantine for 14 days and take a PCR test, but those who can show proof of prior infection and recovery only need to quarantine for one day and don't need to take a PCR test.". You're just claiming that some countries have no COVID restrictions for entry whatsoever and then providing links.